# SQL to update a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-update

So I have a table that has columns such as:

```
RequestID  Owner Name   Owner Email           Date   GUID         Comments (etc)
1          Joe Soap     joe.soap@gmail.com    1/2/19 asdfasdfasdf 
2          Sally Soap   ssoap@hotmail.com     9/7/15 asf2f23f23f2
3          Joe Schmo    jschmo@yahoo.com      1/1/19 af2f2f2f2f2f
4          Adam ABC     abc_adam@adam.com     3/2/18 f89282822828
```

What I've done is exported the table to an excel file and made changes in the excel file.  I've made changes to the 'Owner Email' and 'Owner Name' columns for specific RequestID.

What I'm trying to do is import the three columns to a temp table ("RequestID", "Owner Name", "Owner Email").  I then want to update the main table based on the Request ID.  So it would update the owner name and owner emails such as below:

```
RequestID  Owner Name      Owner Email
3          Joe Schmo Jr    joesnewemailaddr@gmail.com
1          Joe Replacement newjoe@yahoo.com
```

The script I THINK I need is this:

```
UPDATE
    MainTable
SET
    MainTable.OwnerName = New.OwnerName
    MainTable.OwnerEmail = New.OwnerEmail
FROM
    MainTable
INNER JOIN
    UpdateTable
ON 
    MainTable.RequestID = UpdateTable.RequestID
```

This should do it, right?

Comment: Well, when you run the code, is it right?

Comment: Should have clarified - I don't have access to a test environment, so would just like someone to look this over to make sure it checks out before I run it please :)

Comment: `Should have clarified - I don't have access to a test environment, so would just like someone to look this over to make sure it checks out before I run it please :)` <= Wow! That is a horrible idea (sorry, not sure how to phrase that nicely). Do not run an untested query in a production environment and do not solely rely on the internet to test your query for you.

Comment: You can always start a transaction, update the table and then select some sample rows to see if you got the desired result before issuing a commit. The update syntax depends very much on the DBMS you use. There is a Name mismatch UpdateTable / New and a comma missing after New.OwnerName.

Comment: You need to separate the two lines of the `SET` clause with a **comma** at the end of the first line: `MainTable.OwnerName = New.OwnerName, `

Comment: @Igor Haha I would love to see the look on OP's boss's face when they overwrite a ton of production data and the only explanation is "The people on SO said it would be fine!"

Comment: they will make backups prior to this script, so hopefully that is the safeguard :)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That UPDATE FROM code is product specific.)

Comment: Apologies - MS SQL :)  I've updated the tags

Comment: As you are using Excel anyway, you can also just add a formula column to hold single updates: `update maintable set ownername = 'Joe Replacement', owneremail = 'joesnewemailaddr@gmail.com' where requestid = 1;` and them run them all.

Comment: Were your [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) rights revoked? You ought to be able to test it there.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thank you - I had considered that, but to my knowledge there's no way to run one update statement - it would have to be broken into multiple, so if I know i'm supposed to update 7501 records (for example), it would show "1 row updated.  1 row updated.  1 row updated" - so no easy way to make sure it did update the right amount of records if I run multiple update statements, right?

Comment: @HABO didn't know about sqlfiddle.  Very cool, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the "UpdateTable" is the temp table?  Your SQL isn't right, but you don't specify a DBMS either, so here it goes:

```
UPDATE
   MainTable
SET
   MainTable.OwnerName = New.OwnerName,
   MainTable.OwnerEmail = New.OwnerEmail
FROM
   MainTable
INNER JOIN
   UpdateTable AS New
 ON 
   MainTable.RequestID = New.RequestID
```

Notice how I alias the UpdateTable as *New*. However you could have just omitted the `New` alias and used `UpdateTable` in your SET.

```
UPDATE
   MainTable
SET
   MainTable.OwnerName = UpdateTable.OwnerName,
   MainTable.OwnerEmail = UpdateTable.OwnerEmail
FROM
   MainTable
INNER JOIN
   UpdateTable
 ON 
   MainTable.RequestID = UpdateTable.RequestID
```

Comment: Thank you :)  Much appreciated